# Read process output after kill it

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm executing generate.py using subprocess. The problem is that after killing the process I iterate it but reads nothing. I tried all three solutions from link, but don't work:  https://bugs.python.org/issue3907. I'm assuming then that I'm missing something in generate.py.

```
# generate.py
while True:
    for id in ['a','b','c','d']:
        sys.stdout.write('%s\n' % id)

# run_process.py
    chars = set()
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ["python", "generate.py"],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        env=env)
    time.sleep(2)
    process.kill()
    for char in process.stdout.readlines():
        chars.add(char)
    print(f'chars_set: {chars}')
```

Comment: Actually  using `process.kill()` you send `SIGKILL` signal to the process. Why you do not want to send `SIGUSR1` signal?

Comment: No reason, just looking for some solution, any idea why chars remains empty?